# Get Data from selected dates by a datepicker calendar

Tags: php, jquery, html, datepicker

Hello I have a datepicker calendar and what I want is that we I select the two dates then I want to click on a button it displays me all the data which are between those dates.

Here is my code...

```
<?php
include_once 'header.php';


$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','smogi','project');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
$view = ($_GET['view']);
$username2 =$_SESSION['username'];
$sql="SELECT typeValue,unit,sensorValue,time FROM sensors WHERE username='$view' AND time BETWEEN $firstdate AND $lastdate  ORDER BY time DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
echo "<table>
<tr>


</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr> <b>Type: </b>";
    echo stripslashes($row['typeValue']) . "<br/><b>Unit: </b>";
    echo stripslashes($row['unit']) . "<br/><b>Value: </b>";
    echo stripslashes($row['sensorValue']) . "<br/><b>Date & Time: </b>";
    echo stripslashes($row['time']) . "<br/>";
    echo "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------";
    echo "<br/></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var firstdate = $('#firstdatepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();
    //$( "#firstdatepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>


    <script>
  $(function() {
    var lastdate = $('#lastdatepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();
    //$( "#lastdatepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 <form method="post" action="graph.php">
<p>First Date: <input type="text" id="firstdatepicker"></p>

<p>Last Date: <input type="text" id="lastdatepicker"></p>

<input type="submit" value="Get Data" name="data"/>

</form>


</body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't work as I want. Can you help me please to make it work ???

Thank you for your time .

PS: in the image below we can see how my database table look like

[image]

Comment: I had to perform a rollback to [your original question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29901179/1). You placed quotes around your variables where you did not have them originally and should have been marked as an edit under your original post. Just in case people see my answer and ask themselves: *"There's quotes there, so why the answer?"* ;-) *cheers*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, you never define `$firstdate` `$lastdate`. You should like this:

```
$firstdate = $_POST['firstdatepicker'];
$lastdate = $_POST['lastdatepicker'];
```

If it's as you have it in your "time" column, they need to be quoted.

```
BETWEEN '$firstdate' AND '$lastdate'
```

using error checking on your query would have thrown a syntax error

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

I.e.: `$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));`

MySQL reads `datetime` as `YYYY-mm-dd`

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html

You're using `dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'`

Plus, give your inputs name attributes:

```
<input type="text" id = "firstdatepicker" name = "firstdatepicker">
<input type="text" id = "lastdatepicker" name = "lastdatepicker">
```

and adding

```
$firstdate = $_POST['firstdatepicker'];
$lastdate = $_POST['lastdatepicker'];
```

as stated above.

Comment: these values I am getting them from the scripts for example `var firstdate = $('#firstdatepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();`  &  `var lastdate = $('#lastdatepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();`

Comment: @DogFace reload my answer

Comment: Yes I know that , this is way i convert and this is how it looks (http://prntscr.com/6yt3x7)

Comment: @DogFace did you not wrap your variables in quotes as I stated in my answer? and add `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to your query, also stated in my answer.

Comment: @DogFace plus, you're using sessions `$username2 =$_SESSION['username'];` did you start the session?

Comment: yes I insert quotes in my variables, my form look like this (http://prntscr.com/6yt5ud) but when I click it , it doesnt do anything , just reloads the page

Comment: @DogFace another thing is `$view = ($_GET['view']);` I don't know how you're fetching that as there is nothing for "view" in your posted question, plus your form is using a POST method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76375/discussion-between-dogface-and-fred-ii).

Comment: sorry for asking a personal request in order to help me but please please can you take a look at it ??? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926717/google-chart-api-make-use-of-datetime-value)

Comment: @DogFace I'd like to help, but TBH, I suck at arrays. Could never wrap my head around them.

Comment: Hmm, ok thank you for your time :) ... I am searching for a solution over stack and google for 5 hours :-/ .... I dont know what to do ... Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add the `name="firstdatepicker"` and `name="lastdatepicker"` in your form and you need to fill your variables from $_POST superglobal array (and I **desperately hope** you don't use register_globals=on).

Updated HTML part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#firstdatepicker, #lastdatepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
  });
</script>

<form method="post" action="graph.php">
<p>First Date: <input type="text" name="firstdatepicker" id="firstdatepicker"></p>

<p>Last Date: <input type="text" name="lastdatepicker" id="lastdatepicker"></p>

<input type="submit" value="Get Data" name="data"/>

</form>
```

On the PHP side:

```
if (isset($_POST['firstdatepicker'])) {
  $firstDate= $_POST['firstdatepicker'];
  $lastDate= $_POST['lastdatepicker'];

  // forgot the single quotes around the dates ...
  $sql="SELECT typeValue,unit,sensorValue,time FROM sensors WHERE username='$username2' AND time BETWEEN '$firstdate' AND '$lastdate'  ORDER BY time DESC";
}
```

Comment: That's not a very helpful comment ;) I updated the answer (forgot single quotes), could you add `die($sql);` before the closing bracket and post the results of it?

Comment: the textfields in order to select the dates are now disappeared